# Error 500 after successful authentication OAuth 2.0 when hosted on IONOS widows

Tags: windows, .net-core, oauth-2.0, ionos

Would appreciate any advice or guidance you can give.

Attempting to authenticate with Google and Microsoft API.
using nugets Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount

As per documents:-
[Facebook, Google, and external provider authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)
[Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

All works fine on my development PC but after uploading to the host site (IONOS windows hosting)
I get the following error after a successful authentication:-

TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, bool telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)

AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

I get a similar response when authenticating with Microsoft as well.

Details:-
I have a webapp in c# NET 8.0 core MVC style.

Program.cs has:-

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie("social_login")
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
    {
        microsoftOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
        microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"]; 
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
            builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

        googleOptions.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
    });

    
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseFileServer();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

//For x-frame-options errpr:-
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod());

app.Run();
```

Google api:-
[image]

The Requested URL looks like this:-
[https://example.com/signin-google?state={removed}&code={removed}&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=1&prompt=consent](https://example.com/signin-google?state=%7Bremoved%7D&code=%7Bremoved%7D&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=1&prompt=consent)

As I'm aware that IONOS uses proxy servers I added:-

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Also tried adding

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```